# dynamically creating selectManyCheckbox with tooltip

Tags: jsf, richfaces, tooltip, selectmanycheckbox

I have a HashMap in the backing bean and I want to dynamically render multiple select box. Here is the code:

```
    <h:selectManyCheckbox
      id="id"
      value="#{backingBean.value}"
      layout="pageDirection"
      styleClass="label"
      required="true"
      requiredMessage="You must select at least...">


      <a4j:repeat var="aGroup" items="#{backingBean.map}">

        <f:selectItem id="role#{aGroup.value.property1}" itemLabel="#{aGroup.value.property1}" itemValue="#{aGroup.value.property2}" />

        <rich:tooltip for="role" value="#{aGroup.value.property5}" />

     </a4j:repeat>

    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

It is not rendering. 
Using the f:selectItems tag, it is rendering, but I need to manually create the f:selecteItem as I have to attach a rich:tooltip with each f:selectItem.

Any ideas ?

Ravi

Comment: You are not attaching the `rich:tooltip` to the `selectItem`, it is not enclosed inside the `f:selectItem` tag, and the `for` value does not match the `id`

Comment: that is a good point. I corrected that and it is still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<c:forEach>` instead of `<a4j:repeat>`.

First add this namespace at the top of your page.

```
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
```

Now replace `<a4j:repeat.....` with this.

```
<c:forEach var="aGroup" items="#{backingBean.map}">
```

EDIT:

---

I don't think that `<rich:toolTip>` can be applied to `<f:selectItem>`. As a weird hack you can do something like this.

This is your `managed-bean` which returns the `list` or a `map`. Here I'm using a map because it seems you are using a map.

```
public class MyBean {
  private Map<Integer, String> map;

  public Map<Integer, String> getMap() {
    map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    map.put(1, "Tool tip 1");
    map.put(2, "Tool tip 2");
    map.put(3, "Tool tip 3");
    return map;
  }
}
```

Now your `xhtml` code would be like this. Here I'm rendering `selectItem`s dynamically. However this is not necessary for this to work.

```
<h:form id="myForm">
    <h:selectManyCheckbox id="myChkBox" layout="pageDirection" styleClass="label" required="true" requiredMessage="You must select at least...">
        <c:forEach var="aGroup" items="#{myBean.map}">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="someValue1" itemLabel="someValue1" id="someId#{aGroup.key}" /> 
            <span class="rich-tool-tip" id="span#{aGroup.key}" style="z-index: 99; visibility: visible; display: none;">
                <span>#{aGroup.value}</span>
            </span>
            <script>
                var i = !i ? 0 : i;
                new ToolTip("span#{aGroup.key}","myForm:myChkBox:" + i,{'showEvent':'mouseover'} );
                i++;
            </script>
        </c:forEach>
    </h:selectManyCheckbox>
    <rich:toolTip rendered="false"/>
</h:form>
```

That is it...
Note the `<rich:toolTip>` which is set as `rendered="false"`. This is required. Otherwise some important `JS` parts are not imported and your `toolTip` will not work.

Comment: The `<f:selectItems>` is a much easier approach. But OP actually wanted to style each checkbox label.

Comment: @prageeth to rule out the loop issue, i hard coded one one f:selecteItem and tool tip doesn't show up.

    <f:selectItem itemValue="someValue" itemLabel="someValue"    id="someId" >
 <rich:tooltip value="Testing ToolTip" for="someId">      </rich:tooltip>
    </f:selectItem>

Comment: @Ravi: I don't think that `<f:selectItem>` supports `<rich:toolTip>`. However there are dirty hacks for this(even in client side). If you still need to depend on `<rich:toolTip>` I can provide a sample.

Comment: @prageeth I am doing the UI in an alternative way, but I would like to see the solution. If you can provide the sample, that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can't add additional markup/components on a `<f:selectItem>`.

There's also nothing in standard JSF or RichFaces libraries which allows markup freedom on labels of a checkbox group. Only [Tomahawk `<t:selectManyCheckbox>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk20/tagdoc/t_selectManyCheckbox.html) supports it when using `layout="spread"` with `<t:checkbox>`. PrimeFaces has this feature also [on schedule](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3487) for its `<p:selectManyCheckbox>`.

Here's a kickoff example how you could achieve it with Tomahawk:

```
<!-- Below displays nothing due to layout="spread". -->
<t:selectManyCheckbox id="foo" value="#{bean.selectedItems}" layout="spread">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.availableItems}" />
</t:selectManyCheckbox>

<!-- Below displays the concrete checkboxes with labels. -->
<c:forEach items="#{bean.availableItems}" var="item" varStatus="loop">
    <t:checkbox for="foo" index="#{loop.index}" />
    <h:outputLabel id="label#{loop.index}" value="#{item.label}" />
    <rich:tooltip for="label#{loop.index}" value="#{item.tooltip}" />
</c:forEach>
```